# How to grab environment variables using wild card?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have several environment variables set in my makefile that all have a common prefix, and others that do not share the prefix. How can I grab all of the variables that **do** have that prefix, and prepend a `-D` to the front of it, and set those all to a new variable? See below:

```
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
=====================

FOOD_VEGETABLE
FOOD_FRUIT
FOOD_DESSERT
HEAT
GAS
```

So I want a new variable `FOOD_FEATURES` to grab all of the `FOOD_*` variables, and prepend a `-D` prefix. If I printed `FOOD_FEATURES` I would get this:

```
$(warning $(FOOD_FEATURES))
```

gives

```
-DFOOD_VEGETABLE -DFOOD_FRUIT -DFOOD_DESSERT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sufficiently new version of GNU make, you can use the `.VARIABLES` special variable for this sort of introspection:

```
FOOD_FEATURES := $(patsubst %,-D%,$(filter FOO_%,$(.VARIABLES)))
```

I should point out that this will match all make variables containing the prefix `FOO_`, not just environment variables.  If you really want only environment variables that's doable, but much more complex; something like:

```
FOOD_FEATURES := $(patsubst %,-D%,$(foreach V,$(filter FOO_%,$(.VARIABLES)),$(if $(filter environment,$(origin $V)),$V)))
```